# Function not working after $(window).resize(function() {...}) was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need you help.

I don't know what is the problem in my code, in initial load the function works properly, but when I resize the window, the function will not work properly.

here's my js

```
var firedData = true;
    var pcNavigation = function() {
        $('body').find('.appendNavClick').remove();
    };

    var appendToggleButton = function() {
       $('nav').find('a[href^="#toggle"]').remove();
       $.each($('.navigation > li'), function(i, value) {
           if($(value).children('.sub-menu').length == 1) {
               var styleString = 'style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 1px; background: #232323;"';
               $('<a class="appendNav appendNavClick" href="#toggle" '+ styleString +'><span></span></a>').insertAfter($(value).children('a'));
           }
       });
    };

    var spNavigation = function() {
       appendToggleButton();
       $('body').delegate('#menu-main-navigation li > a[href^="#toggle"]', 'click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var self = $(this),
              nextSelector = self.next();
           if(self.parent('li').siblings().find('a[href^="#toggle"]').next().is(':visible')) {
              self.parent('li').siblings().find('a[href^="#toggle"]').toggleClass('sub-menu-open').next().slideUp();
           }
           self.toggleClass('sub-menu-open');
           nextSelector.stop().slideToggle();
       });
    };

    var initResponsive = function() {
       let getResponsive = $(window).width();
       $('.navigation li .sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
       if(getResponsive < 767) {
           spNavigation();
       } else {
           pcNavigation();
       }
    };

    initResponsive();
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        initResponsive();
    });
```

I'm using also the wordpress framework.

Comment: Which function and how is it not working properly? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I got not error, the `spNavigation()` after resizing the window

Comment: the slideToggle() of jquery not working after I resize the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this by using `bind()` and `unbind()` functions of `jQuery`